# IIF Statement in ReportViewer Returns False

Tags: vb.net, report-viewer2010

Okay so I am trying to do math in this IIF statement in reportviewer. However, all it does is return FALSE in my field. Am I able to do math with an IIF statement or what?

```
=IIF(
     UCase(Fields!Tax.Value) = "YES", 
     Variables!DeptTotal.Value =+(Fields!TotalPriceWithoutTax.Value * (1 + Parameters!Tax.Value)), 
     Variables!DeptTotal.Value =+ (Fields!TotalPriceWithoutTax.Value)
     )
```

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Okay Guys,

I even did a custom codes and it still returns false.

```
Public Function Taxable(Answer AS String, DepartTotal AS Decimal, TotalWithoutTax AS Decimal, Tax AS Decimal) AS Decimal

    If UCase(Answer) = "YES" Then

         DepartTotal += TotalWithoutTax * Tax 

    Else

       DepartTotal +=  TotalWithoutTax

    End If

    Return DepartTotal

End Function
```

Any other sugguestions?

Thanks Again.

EDIT:

This is my taxable function call:

```
=Code.Taxable(Tax, DepartTotal, TotalWithoutTax, txtTax.value)
```

Comment: I am not sure how related this is, but since you use side effects on both "yes" and "no" sides, you may want to read [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1220411/335858). Summary of the linked question: both "yes" and "no" expressions are *always* evaluated.

Comment: In short, use `If()` not `Iif()` unless you're really sure you need to. Even then, it's not advised as it is currently marked as deprecated.

Comment: How would you use IF()? I get a compile error.

Comment: Since your Taxable function returns a **Decimal** type, it cannot possibly return False (a **Boolean**).  Can you show us how you are calling the Taxable function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fix:

The function:

```
Public Function Taxable(Answer AS String, TotalWithoutTax AS Decimal, Tax AS Decimal) AS Decimal

       Dim total AS Decimal = 0

       If UCase(Answer) = "YES" Then

             total = TotalWithoutTax *  (1 + Tax)

        Else
             total = TotalWithoutTax

        End If

        Return total

End Function
```

The Call:

```
Code.Taxable(Fields!Tax.Value, Sum(Fields!TotalPriceWithoutTax.Value), Parameters!Tax.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

UCase(Fields!Tax.Value) = "YES", Tax.value may return false and true or 0 and 1 ,
test it again 
and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: change `=+` to `+=`

Change

```
Variables!DeptTotal.Value =+(Fields!TotalPriceWithoutTax.Value * (1 + Parameters!Tax.Value))
```

to

```
Variables!DeptTotal.Value += (Fields!TotalPriceWithoutTax.Value * (1 + Parameters!Tax.Value))
```

Comment: Try `Variables!DeptTotal.Value = Variables!DeptTotal.Value + ((Fields!TotalPriceWithoutTax.Value * (1 + Parameters!Tax.Value)))`

Comment: Still says False. Thanks for the help