# Are both paths evaluated in an ternary operator?

Tags: vb.net

Using vb.net the following code throws a null pointer exception but the expression should guarantee that `match` is not null.

```
repeater.DataSource = IIf(collection IsNot Nothing AndAlso match IsNot Nothing, collection.FindAll(match), collection)
```

Replacing this with regular if-else construct no error is thrown:

```
If collection IsNot Nothing AndAlso match IsNot Nothing Then
    repeater.DataSource = collection.FindAll(match)
Else
    repeater.DataSource = collection
End If
```

Are both path's evaluated in an ternary operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both sides are evaluated, you should avoid the `IIf()` syntax and use the `If()` instead, because `If()` will short-circuit with `AndAlso`.

For more information read the accepted answer to [VB.NET - IIF(,,) - Both “sides” are evaluated. What situations should I watch out for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220411/vb-net-iif-both-sides-are-evaluated-what-situations-should-i-watch-ou).

Comment: I am glad that you accepted the answer, feel free to up-vote the answer as well. :-)

Comment: Better would be to use the IF operator in VB.Net which _does_ short circuit.  IIF is just a normal function.  Habib's answer is the best one.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - I mentioned that `If` will short-circuit in my answer, but you are free to advocate whichever answer you feel is best.

Comment: I don't see any mention of the IF operator in your post.  I see "If-Else" mentioned in conjunction with the AndAlso keyword, but I didn't understand that you meant the IF operator.  I only advocated Habib's answer because he specifically mentioned the IF operator in VB.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - understood. Updating answer to correctly reflect the terminology.

Answer (score 3):

[If Operator (Visual Basic) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx)

> An If operator that is called with three arguments works like an IIf
>   function except that it uses short-circuit evaluation. An **IIf
>   function always evaluates all three of its arguments**