# Decimal? - Nullable object must have a value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, nullable, invalidoperationexception

I'm using **VB.NET MVC 5.1** in **VS2013** using **Razor**

siq.Price is a ***Decimal?***

I'm trying to check if siq.Price has a value, and if so print it as a currency. I recieve this error when trying to access the .Value property for elements where true they returned true for .HasValue:

> **Nullable object must have a value.**
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
> Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
> where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object
> must have a value.

I tried both of these lines of code, believing they should work without issue, yet recieved the error above:

```
@IIf(siq.Price.HasValue, siq.Price.Value, "N/A")
   'and
@IIf(siq.Price.HasValue, siq.Price.Value.ToString("C"), "N/A")
```

As soon as I remove the .Value from the TruePart then it started working:

```
@IIf(siq.Price.HasValue, siq.Price, "N/A")
    'and
@IIf(siq.Price.HasValue, String.Format("{0:C}", siq.Price), "N/A")
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?! I'm rather perplexed.

NOTE: This piece of code works on it's own if the Price has a value, but not in the IIf():

```
@siq.Price.Value.ToString("C")
```

Comment: What is `siq`? How is it defined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET - IIF(,,) - Both "sides" are evaluated. What situations should I watch out for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220411/vb-net-iif-both-sides-are-evaluated-what-situations-should-i-watch-ou)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `IIF()` function in VB.Net always evaluates both the true and false parts. Instead, you should change to use the `IF()` operator, which only evaluates the return value, so something like:

```
@If(siq.Price.HasValue, siq.Price.Value.ToString("C"), "N/A")
```

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, VB.NET's `IIf` method seems equivalent to C#'s ternary operator (?:), but there's a big difference: because it's a method, not an operator, there's no short circuiting, and both parameters are always evaluated before being passed to the method.

What this means is that regardless of whether `HasValue` is true, both `siq.Price.Value` and `"N/A"` are evaluated, leading to the exception you saw.

Comment: Thankyou for your speedy response and useful information. I'll accept the other answer though I'm afraid as it provides a code solution as well as a brief explanation.

Answer (score 0):

IIf() runs both the true and false code. VB's conditional If operator is short-circuit so you can now safely write the following, 
which is not possible using the IIf function:

```
Dim len = If(text Is Nothing, 0, text.Length)
```