# Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid. clickable data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm a newbie to aspx programming. I'm facing the problem where the data I fetch contain null value.
my code :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NCRE" ItemStyle-Width="150px" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Hyperlink ID="Hyperlink1" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("formid") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("formid","~/sapphire/ncrr" + Mid(Eval("formid"), 4, 1) + ".aspx?formid={0}") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And my code behind:

```
Protected Function geturl(value As Object) As String
    Dim NCRE As String = Convert.ToString("formid")
    If Mid(NCRE, 4, 1) = 2 Then
        Return ("~/sapphire/ncrr2.aspx")
    Else
        Return ("~/sapphire/ncrr1.aspx")
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Where does your data come from?

Comment: database table name ncrrtb

Comment: And... some SQL statement?

Comment: im using gridview to pull the data out and display it on table

Comment: select * from ncrrtb where equip_id = @equip_id

Comment: And that doesn't yield any result I guess for that specific ID?

Comment: i have pulled out the result 
is just that some of the data in between is null

Comment: and i wanted to make the data clickable

Comment: So what do you expect to happen when that field is null?

Comment: nothing happen becoz the un"null" data can be lickable to the following link i have shown in code behind.
and i get the error as the title above.

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1979806/993547

Comment: i still don`t understand how do i fix my problem after i see the link u sent to me. sorry =(
i`m a newbie so my understanding is quite limited .

Comment: Copy that method in your code file and use it in the evaluation to make sure it doesn't return `DbNull` but a valid `string`, like `null`.

Comment: @JoeCheong You can use the [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) function in SQL to change NULLs to something else, e.g. `SELECT col1, col2, COALESCE(col3, 'text to say it is blank') FROM ...`.

Answer (score 1):

To help you getting the right code from [the post I've linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1979806/993547):

Copy this part into your code file (ending on `aspx.cs`):

```
Public Function ProcessMyDataItem(myValue As Object) As String
    If myValue Is Nothing OrElse myValue = DbNull.Value Then
        Return "(no value)"
    End If

    Return myValue.ToString()
End Function
```

And in your `.aspx`:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NCRE" ItemStyle-Width="150px" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Hyperlink ID="Hyperlink1" runat="server"  Text='<%# ProcessMyDataItem(Eval("formid")) %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("formid","~/sapphire/ncrr" + Mid(ProcessMyDataItem(Eval("formid")), 4, 1) + ".aspx?formid={0}") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: @PatrickHofman Original answer was in the wrong language. Removed based upon the update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IIf` (`IIf(IsDBNull(Eval("fieldName")) = True, *do what You want when record is empty*, *do what You want when record isn't empty)`).

There are examples :

`Text = '<%# IIf(IsDBNull(Eval("formid")) = True, "no data", Eval("formid))%>'`

Same code You can use for `NavigateUrl` :

`NavigateUrl = '<%# IIf(IsDBNull(Eval("formid")) = True, "#", Eval("formid","~/sapphire/ncrr" + Mid(Eval("formid"), 4, 1) + ".aspx?formid={0}"))'`

And, then, in Your function `geturl` (code behind) first check is `value`, for example `#` (do nothing, or just return empty), otherwise execute code.

Comment: You may be interested in the [If Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb513985%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes, `If` can be used too.

Comment: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments..i got this error ><

Comment: @JoeCheong I suggest that you forget you ever heard of "Iif". It has [gotchas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1220416/1115360).

Answer (score 0):

You may only add an empty string to avoid the error:

Dim NCRE As String = Convert.ToString("formid") & ""

Or, to avoid error at the 4th position:

Dim NCRE As String = Convert.ToString("formid") & "     "