# Error while filling oracle parameters (Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types)

Tags: vb.net, oracle11g

Im trying to add Parameters to the OracleCommand object but an exception is thrown (Object cannot...). What im trying to do is, if a column from the datatable is null, then insert to the database the null value (that column must be empty).
The datatable from where it takes the data is formatted something like this:

```
dt.Columns.Add("NAME", GetType(String))
dt.Columns.Add("AGE", GetType(Integer))
```

Fill

```
dt.Rows(0)("NAME") = DBNull.Value
dt.Rows(0)("AGE") = DBNull.Value
```

Later when inserting the data via procedure:

```
....
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.Add("NAME", OracleType.VarChar).Value = IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("CVV")), OracleClient.OracleString.Null, dt.Rows(0)("CVV")) <-- Seems to work.
cmd.Parameters.Add("AGE"), OracleType.Number).Value = IIf(dt.Rows(0).IsNull("AGE"), OracleClient.OracleNumber.Null, CInt(dt.Rows(0)("AGE"))) <-- Error.
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the If operator. This short-circuit the evaluation of the expression, while Iif does not.

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.Add("NAME", OracleType.VarChar).Value = If(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("CVV")), 
                  OracleClient.OracleString.Null, dt.Rows(0)("CVV")) 
cmd.Parameters.Add("AGE"), OracleType.Number).Value = If(dt.Rows(0).IsNull("AGE"), 
                  OracleClient.OracleNumber.Null, CInt(dt.Rows(0)("AGE")))
```

In the [IIf function both sides of the expression are evaluated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220411/vb-net-iif-both-sides-are-evaluated-what-situations-should-i-watch-ou), so you Cint fails because is called even when is true that the row is null, this is not the case with the [if operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't realize that IIf evaluated both sides. I will fix the code now.

Comment: Hi, it seems that I can't use If sentence, it gets marked as vb.net code and when I build the proyect it fails to do so.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't followed this answer until now (night time here). Is it fine now?

Comment: Yes, it is fine now. Thanks a lot mate.