# Why is my IIF expression in my RDLC report giving me an #Error

Tags: rdlc, zero, iif

We have an RDLC report that needs to perform a calculation based on two values but before we do the calculation we want to check that the divisor is NOT zero. This is our expression:

=IIF(Fields!FundCatTotal.Value > 0, (ReportItems!tbfChangeAmt.Value/Fields!FundCatTotal.Value) * 100, 0)

The "True" part of the expression works fine. Its the "False" part that is giving us an issue. If the Fields!FundCatTotal.Value is not greater than zero the expression generates an #Error in the RDLC report. We are stumped as to why it would do that. The expression is a rather simple one but perhaps we are missing something.

Any ideas?

Comment: dupe of [VB.NET - IIF(,,) - Both "sides" are evaluated. What situations should I watch out for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220411/vb-net-iif-both-sides-are-evaluated-what-situations-should-i-watch-ou) et al.

Comment: i.e. if your divisor is zero, the division is still done, hence the error. use `if()` instead.

Comment: Is the IF() function available in an RDLC expression? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Not seeing it where? In what version of Report Builder or Visual Studio??

Comment: We are using VS2019 Professional. In the expression builder for the RDLC report we do not see an option for IF(). Should it be there?

Comment: I dunno. Type it manually and see if it works.